# fatal exception : main in adapter (Recycler View Adapter)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new to android. I am working on SQL CRUD operations. The app runs without problems but in my adapter, I just replace the **bindItems** method with another way of initializing Ui elements in order to use variables in the Update & Delete operation.

Unfortunately, the app stops and give me **FATAL EXCEPTION: Main error**.

I don't know how to fix it, please help me.

This is the Adapter with bindItems method (The app works fine)

```js
class AdapterRecord (): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecord.MyViewHolder>()  {


    private var context: Context? = null
    private var notesList: List<Note>? = null

    constructor(context: Context?, notesList: List<Note>?) : this() {
        this.context = context
        this.notesList = notesList
    }


    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

       fun bindItems(note: Note) {
           val tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle) as TextView
           val tvDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription) as TextView
           tvTitle.text = note.name
           tvDescription.text = note.description

        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.note_ticket, parent,false)

        return MyViewHolder(itemView)


    }

    override fun getItemCount() : Int {
        return notesList!!.size

    }



    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(notesList!!.get(position))



    }
}
```

And this is the adapter without bindItems (The app stopped working with exception)

```js
class AdapterRecord (): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecord.MyViewHolder>()  {


    private var context: Context? = null
    private var notesList: List<Note>? = null

    constructor(context: Context?, notesList: List<Note>?) : this() {
        this.context = context
        this.notesList = notesList
    }


    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


        val tvTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTitle)
        val tvDescription  = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDescription)

     

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.note_ticket, parent,false)

        return MyViewHolder(itemView)


    }

    override fun getItemCount() : Int {
        return notesList!!.size

    }



    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {



        val note = notesList!!.get(position)

            //get data
            val id = note.id
            val name = note.name
            val description = note.description

            //set data

            holder.tvTitle.text = name
            holder.tvDescription.text = description





    }
}
```

Comment: Ahmad, If you can provide demo project then I can help with debugging.

Comment: what is the fatal exception can you provide the stacktrace log?

Comment: Thank you @HarisDautović.  How can I provide you with demo project and where ?

Comment: I don't understand the question @Zain. sorry I am new to android

Comment: When you run the project on a device and crashes.. There's a crash reportcan be given from Android studio.. The logcat tab at the bottom bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to resolve it and I succeeded.
I create a new class to declare Ui elements but before declaring there is set on content method to the layout which add notes to database then the app works fine.
This is the class :

```js
class UiElements : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note)


        val tvTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTitle)
        val tvDescription  = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDescription)
        val moreBtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.moreBtn)


    }
        }
```